# Google Puppeteer forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the following function:

```
    (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://elgiganten.dk');
    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1200});
    await page.type('#main-search', 'El');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await page.waitForSelector('#no-products');
    //await page.screenshot({path: 'view.png'});

    // execute standard javascript in the context of the page.
    await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
    const foundProducts = await page.evaluate(() => {
        var products = $('.mini-product-content');
        var returnArray = [];

        products.forEach(function (product) {
            var container = product.find('a');
            returnArray.push({
                title: container.title
            });
        });


        return products;
    });
    console.log(foundProducts);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

The class `'.mini-product-content'` exists 14 times on the page. Now as you can see i attempt to loop through them however whenever i do i get the following error:

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: products.forEach is not a function

if i remove it and instead print out the result i get the following:

```
    { '0': {},
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  '3': {},
  '4': {},
  '5': {},
  '6': {},
  '7': {},
  '8': {},
  '9': {},
  '10': {},
  '11': {},
  '12': {},
  '13': {},
  length: 14,
  prevObject: 
   { '0': 
      { location: [Object],
        __satellite__: 2,
        SearchForm: [Object],
        StoreForm: [Object],
        _html5shiv: 1,
        jQuery2240488744717004840461: [Object] },
     length: 1 } }
```

The above is using `console.log`

So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `for of` instead.. eg.  `for (const product of products) {`  products is most likely an iterable, but not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over jQuery list. You should replace `.forEach()` with [jQuery equivalent `.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).